# How can I get coordinates of a path through the remote API of v-rep?

Tags: python, simulator, robotics, motion-planning

Question in the title. Using the remote python API of [v-rep](https://github.com/Troxid/vrep-api-python), I am able to get images and control motor properties of robots, but I cannot find any way to get the coordinates of a path object that was made with the path planning functionality in v-rep. I would like to get them as an array in my external python script.

I have found that there is no remote API functions dedicated to path objects, but there might be a more generic function that could be used for this.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround provided by the developers on the v-rep forum as there does not seem to be a straightforward way to do this:
http://www.forum.coppeliarobotics.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=7095&p=28040#p28040

First sample the path coordinates with simGetPathPosition, inside of a script function. Then call that script function from the python remote Api client, via simxCallScriptFunction.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code to extract the coordinates `errorCode, sensor_handle = vrep.simxGetObjectHandle(clientID, 'GPS', vrep.simx_opmode_oneshot_wait)`